# Symfony 3.4 controller registered as service throws deprecation warning

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a controller, let's say `Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController`

And its definition in `services.yml` is as follows:

```
services:
    Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController:
        class: Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController
        arguments: ['@product_service']
```

Which throws this in my log file:

```
User Deprecated: The "Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController" service is private, checking for its existence is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0.
```

Followed by

```
User Deprecated: The "Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController" service is private, getting it from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
```

The stack trace list of files is completely inside `vendor/symfony` so I'm assuming something is misconfigured, but stumped as to what. Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/conventions.html - From time to time, some classes and/or methods are deprecated in the framework; that happens when a feature implementation cannot be changed because of backward compatibility issues, but we still want to propose a "better" alternative. In that case, the old implementation can be deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller service must be public:

```
services:
    Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController:
        public: true
        arguments: ['@product_service']
```

Why aren't you using autowiring anyway? You could register all of your controllers then:

```
Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Acme/ShopBundle/Controller' # mutatis mutandis
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Kindly read about new features regarding dependency management in Symfony 3.

Comment: I am auto wiring controllers, but this controller needs to have a `@product_service` as its first argument - otherwise I receive: `Type error: Too few arguments to function Acme\ShopBundle\Controller\ProductListController::__construct()`

Comment: But thanks, setting `public: true` resolves this notice

Comment: Instead of making it public you really should tag it as a controller:  tags: ['controller.service_arguments'] I should add that if you let autowire do it's thing then you won't need a service definition at all.